# How to always show NFC/location/Bluetooth icons on status bar when on?

Tags: samsung, notification-bar

I have Samsung Galaxy A14 with Android 13. My problem is that the icons for NFC, Bluetooth and location are only shown in the status bar when they're currently active, for example when I'm connected to another Bluetooth device. I want them to show up on the status bar *always* when they're on, so that I can turn them off if I forgot to do that. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

For these functionalities, you can consider using a home screen widget
To get native icon in status bar, custom ROMs might be only solution but it might not be feasible to you

Comment: Thanks, I ended up using [this app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=it.sourcenetitalia.togglestatuswidget). But I don't understand why it isn't a built-in functionality.